# How to get Token Name on Invalid Token result in Struts 2

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, struts2, token, interceptor

How can I get the invalid token's name, when interceptor returns `"invalid.token"` result?

**More details:** I want to renew the token in Ajax calls, when it is invalid. `tokenSession` interceptor, returns this result:

```
<result name="invalid.token">results/test_error_csrfResult.jsp</result>
```

then I want to get the invalid token's name in this JSP page and renew it.

Comment: Why do you need to renew it? If result is returned then there is already new token.

Comment: @AleksandrM: In Ajax calls, when the result is "invalid.token", I want to renew it

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the parameter from the action context by the name `"struts.token.name"`.

```
ActionContext.getContext().getParameters().get("struts.token.name");
```

Comment: token name is variable, depending on forms function. also that jsp page is common between different forms.

Comment: Also! When the interceptor returns "invalid.token" the params is not accessible with this method